# Java Soap web service connection: could not send Message

Tags: java, spring, web, soap

When I Try to connect a soap webservice with java, I take an exeption about like this

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.     at
> org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.mapException(JaxWsClientProxy.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.hastaHizmetVerileriGetir(Unknown Source)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.inte   at
> org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine$$Lambda$361/0000000000000000.accept(Unknown
> Source)   at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:497)
> at java.base/ja     at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
> **Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response
> '404: Not Found' when communicating with
> url.example.com   at**
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1619)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1626)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1571)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1371)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:671)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
> at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
> at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441)   at
> org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356)    at
> org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)    at
> org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
> ... 53 more

```
private IESHIstanbul getPort(CortexEvdeSaglikClientContext context,
 String methodName) {
 
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean serviceProxyFactoryBean =
 WsUtils.getServiceProxyFactoryBean(IESHIstanbul.class,
 context.getUrl());

    SoapLogInfo soapLogInfo = new SoapLogInfo();
    soapLogInfo.setUrl(context.getUrl());
    soapLogInfo.setMethodName(methodName);
 
    soapHandlerService.getLoggingHandler(soapLogInfo);
 
    Object port = serviceProxyFactoryBean.create();

    WsUtils.setServiceEndPoint(port, context.getUrl());
 
    return (IESHIstanbul) port; }
```

This about org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response
'404: Not Found'.

I have made some research about it but, I couldn't find any valuable solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what is `context.getUrl()` and how it looks like? Also did you try to invoke that service using different client like SoapUI?

Comment: context.getUrl() I call Url that I want to connect, Yes I can connect with SoapUI and I can take response but, I could'nt it with java, After I connect with SoapUI, I exported definitations and I created wsdl classes via wsimport